# v-on:click="{{item.klik}}" using VUE

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Im developing a web page and I have a problem with  that sentence. Nothing happens when I click on the element.

```
<li  v-for="(item,indice) of tasks" v-on:click="{{item.klik}}"> 
        <a> <img v-bind:src="item.src" ><b v-bind:id="item.id"> {{item.title}}</b></li>
```

Also I declared everything:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      tasks: [
        {
          title: 'NUEVA RECEPCIÓN',
          src: 'images/add.png',
          id: 'item-title2',
          klik: 'toggle_visibility()'
        },
        {
          title: 'EDITAR RECEPCIÓN ',
          src: 'images/document_check_edit.png',
          id: 'item-title3',
          klik: 'none'
        },
        {
          title: 'ELIMINAR RECEPCIÓN ',
          src: 'images/error.png',
           id: 'item-title4',
        },
        {
          title: 'FINALIZAR RECEPCIÓN ',
          src: 'images/check.png',
           id: 'item-title5',
        },
        {
          title: 'ASIGNAR MATERIAL ',
          src: 'images/box_into.png',
           id: 'item-title6',
        },
        {
          title: 'ELIMINAR MATERIAL ',
          src: 'images/box_out.png',
           id: 'item-title7',
        },
        {
          title: 'IMPRIMIR ETIQUETA ',
          src: 'images/receipt_printer.png',
           id: 'item-title8',
        },
      ]
    }
  })
```

Does anyone know why when I click  on the element nothing happens?
Thank you!

Comment: It should be `v-on:click="item.klik"` to begin with but I doubt that will work since you are mapping your `klik` property to strings and not actual methods. If you want to map to methods you should at least remove the single quotes around stuff like: `toggle_visibility()`.

Comment: Actually there is another problem here. Even if you bind `item.klik`, its not going to call that function necessarily.

Comment: Here's how I might handle that click. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/bYNvJb?editors=1010